# Data in the table view won't show

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I want to show data in my table view, but the data won't show, based on the youtube video I have watched on [here](https://youtu.be/bXHinfFMkFw) the data should show based on the dummy data I have inputed. Here's my code for the view controller and viewcell

MenuViewController

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    let searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar()
    
    // Table View
    let tableView = UITableView()
    var menus: [Menu] = []
    
    struct Cells {
        static let menuTableViewCell = "MenuTableViewCell"
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Table View
        configureTableView()
        menus = fetchData()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.tintColor = .black
        
        // Title
        self.navigationItem.title = "Dashboard"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        
        // Search Bar
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.default
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search menu..."
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange textSearched: String) {
        // code
    }
    
    func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        setTableViewDelegates()
        tableView.rowHeight = 120
        tableView.register(MenuTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: Cells.menuTableViewCell)
        tableView.pin(to: view)
    }
    
    func setTableViewDelegates(){
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension MenuViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menus.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.menuTableViewCell) as! MenuTableViewCell
        let menu = menus[indexPath.row]
        cell.set(menu: menu)
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

// Dummy data
extension MenuViewController {
    func fetchData() -> [Menu] {
        let cake1 = Menu(image: CakeImages.cake1!, category: "Cheesecake", name: "Choco Hazelnut Cheesecake", size: "16 cm (125k) & 20cm (225k)")
        let cake2 = Menu(image: CakeImages.cake2!, category: "Cheesecake", name: "Lotus Cheesecake", size: "16 cm (115k) & 20cm (215k)")
        let cake3 = Menu(image: CakeImages.cake3!, category: "Cheesecake", name: "Oreo Cheesecake", size: "16 cm (115k) & 20cm (215k)")
        let cake4 = Menu(image: CakeImages.cake4!, category: "Cheesecake", name: "Strawberry Cheesecake", size: "16 cm (125k) & 20cm (225k)")
        let cake5 = Menu(image: CakeImages.cake5!, category: "Cheesecake", name: "Blueberry Cheesecake", size: "16 cm (135k) & 20cm (235k)")
        let cake6 = Menu(image: CakeImages.cake6!, category: "Cheesecake", name: "Orange Marmalade Cheesecake", size: "16 cm (125k) & 20cm (225k)")
        let cake7 = Menu(image: CakeImages.cake7!, category: "Fresh Cream", name: "Strawberry Shortcake", size: "15 cm (195k)")
        let cake8 = Menu(image: CakeImages.cake8!, category: "Fresh Cream", name: "Fraisier Cheese Cake", size: "15 cm (195k)")
        let cake9 = Menu(image: CakeImages.cake9!, category: "Fresh Cream", name: "Chocolate Cake", size: "15 cm (195k)")
        let cake10 = Menu(image: CakeImages.cake10!, category: "Fresh Cream", name: "Vanilla Lotus Biscoff", size: "15 cm (195k)")
        
        return [cake1, cake2, cake3, cake4, cake5, cake6, cake7, cake8, cake9, cake10]

    }
}
```

MenuTableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class MenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    // Menu variable
    var cakeImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 96, height: 96))
    let cakeCategory = UILabel()
    let cakeName = UILabel()
    let cakeSize = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(cakeImageView)
        addSubview(cakeCategory)
        addSubview(cakeName)
        addSubview(cakeSize)
        
        // Layout
        configureImageView()
        configureCakeCategory()
        configureCakeName()
        configureCakeSize()
        
        // Constraints
        setImageConstraints()
        setCakeCategoryConstraints()
        setCakeNameConstraints()
        setCakeSizeConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func set(menu: Menu) {
        cakeImageView.image = menu.image
        cakeCategory.text = menu.category
        cakeName.text = menu.name
        cakeSize.text = menu.size
    }
    
    // Image View
    func configureImageView() {
        cakeImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        cakeImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    func setImageConstraints() {
        cakeImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cakeImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        cakeImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        cakeImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
        cakeImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cakeImageView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    // Cake Category
    func configureCakeCategory() {
        cakeCategory.numberOfLines = 0
        cakeCategory.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }
                                                     
    func setCakeCategoryConstraints() {
        cakeCategory.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cakeCategory.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        cakeCategory.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cakeImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        cakeCategory.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        cakeCategory.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true    }
    
    // Cake Name
    func configureCakeName() {
        cakeName.numberOfLines = 0
        cakeName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }
    
    func setCakeNameConstraints() {
        cakeName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cakeName.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        cakeName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cakeImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        cakeName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        cakeName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    }
    
    // Cake Size
    func configureCakeSize() {
        cakeSize.numberOfLines = 0
        cakeSize.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }
    
    func setCakeSizeConstraints() {
        cakeSize.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cakeSize.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        cakeSize.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cakeImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        cakeSize.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        cakeSize.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    
    }
    
}
```

The data should be shown, if I try to add more data to the table view, the row increase, but the data won't show

Comment: It would be easier to use a UITableViewController than a UIViewController with your own table view.

Comment: One big issue is in `cellForRowAt`. Replace `return UITableViewCell()` with `return cell`.

Comment: @HangarRash I don't realize that, thank you so much for your help, it's already solve